# RecyclerView looses the previous position and jumps to zero position when a top menu above it is Visible and then Gone

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In an Android application,

In a vertical LinearLayout,
I have a top menu and then a RecyclerView with multiple view types below that top menu

Some settings are done through the recyclerview items and when a setting is changed in an item, the user can see the result of that change in the top menu

In fact, the top menu is normally closed and when the user decides to see that menu, he/she clicks on a button to see the menu and if he/she clicks again, the menu is closed

To open and close the menu, I use set visibility of the items in the menu to **Visible and Gone**

The problem is when I scroll down the items in the RecyclerView and change the interested setting and then when I click on the mentioned button to see the result on the top menu and then click again to close the menu and see the RecyclerView again, ***then the RecyclerView looses the position where I implemented the setting and goes to the 0 position and exhibits the first items of the RecyclerView***

**The point is it does not loose the position when I'm in the position lower that 35**
In fact there is no problem with below 35 items but if I scroll to the 36th item and click the mentioned button to see the menu and then click again to see the RecyclerView items, the problem appears and I see the first item (0) of the RecyclerView

Why there is a difference between lower and uper items of the RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

I finally had to use **SharedPreferences** to save the positions and then restore them and use **scrollToPositionWithOffset** to work around the issue